# What could be the reason of not showing debugs in logs?

Tags: apex, batch

In batches I can't see debugs in logs and variables aren't changed inside batches but batches run and IDE shows 'Success'. What may be the reason of that? I checked in my organization and for 3 batches debug logs aren't visible and in one batch debug log is visible. (Debug logs were there)

Comment: Are all the batches directly implemented in your org or are they from a managed package?

Comment: They are directly implemented.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your [TraceFlag](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_traceflag.htm) settings at the time the batch runs, as well as if the [maximum debug log size](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_debug_log.htm&type=5) is reached. If your trace flags are not set right, or if the log is truncated because of size, you may not see the debug statements. You may want to use [Check Points](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_checkpoints_setting.htm&type=5) if you absolutely want to see the data at a given point in execution. The Developer Console can be used to set and view check point data, but you'll need to set your Apex Trace Flag to INFO (you can check this in Debug > Change Log Levels...).